Does <AccountInfo> have the accont key?
Looking at getMultipleAccountInfo it returns a
AccountInfo<T>: {
    data: T;
    executable: boolean;
    lamports: number;
    owner: PublicKey;
    rentEpoch?: number;
}

Am I correct in assuming it is not possible to get the account key from this, instead we would need to return it inside data?

NOTE: I am calling getProgramAddress which returns a list of AccountInfo objects. I would like to get the public address related to each account.

I didn't realize that getProgramAddress returns AccountInfo and pubKey. So I should be able to ready the pubkey on the returned value.
